# Why are Thompson's groups called $F$, $T$ and $V$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ho.history-overview, notation

> Why are [Thompson's groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_groups) called $F$, $T$ and $V$?

I never saw Thompson's unpublished notes, in which he introduces these groups; maybe an explanation can be found there?

Comment: The groups I am referring to are those described here: [Introductory notes on Richard Thompson's groups](http://people.math.binghamton.edu/matt/thompson/cfp.pdf).

Comment: Note: there are several Richard Thompson referred in MathSciNet; the concerned one is Richard J. Thompson.

Comment: I think that $V$ was initially denoted as $G$ (it's the case in Higman's 1974 notes, where he denotes $V_{n,r}$ the free $n$-Jónsson-Tarski algebra on $r$ generators and $G_{n,r}$ its automorphism group, known as Thompson-Higman group now).

Comment: Looking at the notes, where past naming is discussed, I am guessing $F$ came from finiteness properties ($FP_\infty$) and for some reason it stuck

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The "$F$" actually stands for "free homotopy idempotent", since $F$ is the universal group encoding a free homotopy idempotent (the endomorphism sending each standard generator $x_i$ to $x_{i+1}$ is idempotent up to conjugation). The universality was proved by [Freyd–Heller](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(93)90088-B) (who called it "$F$" for this reason), and independently Dydak. The group was subsequently sometimes called the "Freyd–Heller group", giving the notation $F$ a double meaning. Then people realized Thompson had worked with the group before Freyd–Heller did, and started calling it "Thompson's group $F$". The "$T$" just stands for "Thompson". The "$V$" is a little mysterious; for a while it was denoted "$G$" but I think people just realized "G" was bad notation for a specific group, and somehow "$V$" emerged as a good option since it wasn't being used, or something (actually, according to [Cannon–Floyd–Parry](http://people.math.binghamton.edu/matt/thompson/cfp.pdf), Thompson called it $\hat{V}$ in his unpublished handwritten notes, so maybe that's part of the reason).

(P.S. This is Matt Zaremsky, I don't really use MathOverflow but I thought I should answer this question!)

Comment: welcome to MathOverflow, professor Zaremsky! by the way, you might consider registering so that this "user 164670" ID becomes more informative...

Comment: On the other hand you might prefer to retain a mild degree of anonymity, because my experience is that if you are easily contactable then you will be contacted with lots of questions, requests for help, etc.

Comment: I added a link to [Freyd–Heller](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(93)90088-B), and, since [e-Periodica](http://e-periodica.ch) seems to be down and I couldn't find it through MathSciNet, copied @AGenevois's [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331248/why-are-thompsons-groups-called-f-t-and-v#comment826050_331248) to [Cannon–Floyd–Parry](http://people.math.binghamton.edu/matt/thompson/cfp.pdf), but I couldn't figure out which of the many many many articles by [Dydak](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?pg4=AUCN&s4=Dydak) was meant.  Maybe you could clarify?

Comment: The Dydak paper is called, "A simple proof that pointed FANR-spaces are regular fundamental retracts of ANR’s." And yeah, registering is probably smart, I just figured out how!

Comment: Concerning the names in Thompson's original notes: $F$ is called $\mathbb{P}$ as given by its finite presentation and $\hat{\mathbb{P}}$ as generated by piecewise linear homeomorphisms (so $\mathbb{P} \cong \hat{\mathbb{P}}$; $T$ is called $C$; and $V$ is indeed called $V$ (and there are hat versions of both of these as well).

Answer (score 5):

Matt Zaremsky's [justification](https://mathoverflow.net/a/370677) of "$F$" for "free" can also be found in Ross Geoghegan's review [MR1239554](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1239554) on Mathscinet.

I also took a look at McKenzie and Thompson's article *An elementary construction of unsolvable word problems in group theory* ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=396769)) (which seems to be the first publication mentioning the groups constructed by Thompson), and there is some history in §8. Below is a screenshot:

[image: Excerpt from McKenzie and Thompson's "An elementary construction of unsolvable word problems in group theory"]

The groups $\mathfrak{P}$ and $\mathfrak{P}'$ correspond to the group now called $F$. From the context, $\mathfrak{P}$ probably refers to the "p" of "permutation". The group $\mathfrak{C}'$ corresponds to the group now called $V$. I would guess that $\mathfrak{C}$ refers to the "C" of "Cantor space".

Comment: Concerning the names $C$ vs. $V$ Thompson writes in the notes I have "(Let $\hat{V}$ be the $\mathcal{C}'$ of p. 475 of Word Problems adjusted to the reals\ldots)" which raises questions of chronology I cannot resolve.